# Rotating UIView including the CALayer bounds AND the CALayer frame

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, core-animation, calayer

I want to rotate my "containerView" UIView (semi-transparent red box in the screenshot) using `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` and then later (after it rotates) add sublayers to the view's layer, but I'm finding that only the containerView.layer's bounds are resized, and NOT the containerView.layer's frame! :(

Here's how it looks in portrait:

[image: portrait]

Example code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    CALayer *r = [CALayer layer];
    r.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
    r.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"r.png"] CGImage];
    [self.containerView.layer addSublayer:r];
}

- (void)deviceRotated:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    ...
    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        self.containerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(RADIANS(90));
        self.containerView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 411.0, 320.0);

        NSLog(@"container bounds: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.containerView.bounds));
        NSLog(@"container layer frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.containerView.layer.frame));
        NSLog(@"container layer bounds: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.containerView.layer.bounds));

        CALayer *testLayer = [CALayer layer];
        testLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
        testLayer.bounds = self.containerView.layer.frame;
        testLayer.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(testLayer.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(testLayer.bounds));
        [self.containerView.layer addSublayer:testLayer];
    }
}
```

which, after rotating, prints:

```
container bounds: {{0, 0}, {411, 320}}
container layer frame: {{0, 0}, {320, 411}}
container layer bounds: {{0, 0}, {411, 320}}
```

(Notice the layer's frame is still 320 wide, 411 high.)

So now it looks like:

[image: landscape left]

I also tried setting the center before changing the bounds, but that looks like:

[image: landscape left with setting center]

I know that the containerView's layer doesn't autoresize, so I tried just setting the layer's frame after the transform... `self.containerView.layer.frame = self.containerView.bounds;` which then prints out:

```
container bounds: {{0, 0}, {320, 411}}
container layer frame: {{0, 0}, {411, 320}}
container layer bounds: {{0, 0}, {320, 411}}
```

and looks like:

[image: landscape left and setting layer frame]

Argh!

autoResizesSubviews is set to YES for all views, clipsToBounds is set to NO. I can't use `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` because the real app will have a camera preview so I want the root view to remain in portrait.

I must be missing something with how I'm doing the transform on containerView to get its layer's bounds and frame to be the same, but I can't figure out what it is! Any help would be much appreciated.

**Update - Fixed:**

Setting the newly added layer's bounds (`testLayer.bounds`) to `contentView.layer.bounds` INSTEAD of `contentView.layer.frame` did the trick. (Since transforming the contentView invalidates its layer.frame.) Thanks Michael!

Fixed:

[image: contentView.layer.bounds instead of contentView.layer.frame]

Comment: Before i post as an anwser have you tried fliping the values in   self.containerView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 411.0, 320.0);

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried that and it looks like it's almost there: http://f.cl.ly/items/371I0q1O3O0e0E3A0O0P/r_land_bounds_320_411.png - Though the container layer frame is {{-45.5, 45.5}, {411, 320} and the layer's bounds are: {{0, 0}, {320, 411}}

Comment: Frames values are not useful when a view has been transformed. From apple doc Warning: If the transform property is not the identity transform, the value of this(frame) property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

Comment: Just a note here that you should check for the layer already existing in your `viewDidAppear` before adding it, otherwise you could be adding the layer multiple times. For example, anytime you push another view controller onto the stack and release it, `viewDidAppear` will be called again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  self.containerView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 411.0, 320.0);
```

Your setting here is wrong because of the flipped context.  You set it to be wide and because it is flipped 90 degrees it goes back to being vertical.

Comment: Thanks, the only thing is that now the containerView's bounds appear to still be 320 x 411. And if I force them to 411 x 320 I'm back to square one with the layer frame reverting to 320 x 411. :(

Comment: VICTORY!! Since after the transform, the containerView.layer's frame is undefined/ignored, I changed the `testLayer.bounds = self.containerView.layer.frame;` line to `testLayer.bounds = self.containerView.layer.bounds;` and that worked. http://f.cl.ly/items/2k042r3p1e1g3N0H010C/r_land_bounds.png - thanks so much!

Comment: No problem glad i could help, and yeah anytime a transformation happens the frame property becomes garbage

Comment: You know, I actually read that in the docs too at one point, but totally escaped my mind. Thanks again.